# Máscara de dinheiro

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Preciso ter num entry uma máscara de dinheiro, estou tentando algumas coisas que consegui de informações, segue:

```
void lanceMask(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ev = e as TextChangedEventArgs;

        if (ev.NewTextValue != ev.OldTextValue)
        {
            var entry = (Entry)sender;
            string text = Regex.Replace(ev.NewTextValue, @"[^0-9]", "");

            text = text.PadRight(9);

            //Removendo todos os digitos excedentes 
            if (text.Length > 8)
            {
                text = text.Remove(8);
            }

            if (text.Length < 5)
            {
                text = text.Insert(1, ".").TrimEnd(new char[] { ' ', '.', '-', ',' });
            }
            else
            {
                text = text.Insert(5, ".").Insert(7, ",").TrimEnd(new char[] { ' ', '.', '-', ',' });
            }

            if (entry.Text != text)
                entry.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Gostaria de poder utilizar o ponto e vírgula se tivesse 6 dígitos (ex: 1.400,00), se for 7 dígitos (ex: 23.600,00), e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtive resposta de um colega, como outros podem precisar, segue:

```
public void Mascara(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var ev = e as TextChangedEventArgs;
  if (ev.NewTextValue != ev.OldTextValue)
  {
    var entry = (Entry)sender;
    entry.TextChanged -= Mascara;
    string text = Regex.Replace(ev.NewTextValue.Trim(), @"[^0-9]", "");

  if (text.Length > 2)
  {
    text = text.Insert(text.Length - 2, ",");
  }

  if (text.Length > 6)
  {
    text = text.Insert(text.Length - 6, ".");
  }
  if (text.Length > 10)
  {
    text = text.Insert(text.Length - 10, ".");
  }

  if (entry.Text != text)
  entry.Text = text;
  entry.TextChanged += Mascara;
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom. Lembrando que você pode aceitar sua própria resposta :)